# How does PHP determine if session is inactive

Tags: php, ajax, session, garbage-collection, timeout

Iam having difficulty understanding why my sessions are expiring/gc'd even when, for instance,  I am calling a file like "update.php" through ajax every 5sec.

Update.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["blah"]="blah";
session_write_close();
echo "blah";
```

php settings
session.cookie_lifetime 0
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

Question:
How does php actually define "inactivity"?
Does writing the same string into a session variable not count as activity? 
Any feedback will be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: If the session is active then the timestamp of the session file will be the date/time of last access - if the interval between that timestamp and now is > the session lifespan, then it's inactive

Comment: So if the timestamp of the session file is baed on date/time last access, then in my example the session should NEVER be inactive correct?

Comment: If it's within 1440 seconds, it shouldn't be inactive, no

Comment: Ah, so there must something else thats causing the error. One last question, is there any way to access this timestamp value from w/in the php file?Thanks

Comment: I believe that it's the actual mdate for the file entry in the temp directory (or wherever your session files are stored)